# php dom get multiple element from loop

Tags: php, dom

below is my html structure, i want output like : content inside post_message div and respective images

**something like :**

```
test 123 -> 1.png
test 1232 -> 2.png
test 1232 -> 3.png
```

**Html content**

```
<div class="abc">
    <div>
        <div class="udata">
            <div class="post_message"><p>test 123</p></div>
            <div class="">
                <img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="1.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="abc">
    <div>
        <div class="udata">
            <div class="post_message"><p>test 1232</p></div>
            <div class="">
                <img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="2.png">
                <img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="3.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my php code but it seems not working :

```
<?php 
$dom = new DomDocument();
// $dom->load($filePath);
@$dom->loadHTML($fop);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="udata";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

// print_r($nodes);

foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {


    $entries = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'post_message')]", $node);
    print_r($entries);

    $isrc  =  $node->query("//img/@src");
    print_r($isrc);
}
```

Comment: I prefer to you to use `PHP Simple HTML Dom`, it's very usable for work. http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using XPath, you always need to make your XPath relative to the start node, so using the `descendant` axes to ensure you limit the subsequent search is only in the nodes part of the start point.

So the code would look more like...

```
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    $entries = $finder->query("descendant::*[contains(@class, 'post_message')]", $node);
    echo $entries[0]->textContent .":";

    $isrc  =  $finder->query("descendant::img/@src", $node);
    foreach ( $isrc as $src )   {
        echo $src->textContent.",";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

which would output

```
test 123:1.png,
test 1232:2.png,3.png,
```